# How can I disable the multi-touch and the pulling from my activity

Tags: android

I want disable the multi-touch action and the pulling action from my screen and from my activity. I want only use the impact action for my activity. How can I do it?

I want disable the multi-touch and the pulling action from the `a` view.

```
a.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getX(0)>=20 && event.getY(0)>=60 && event.getX(0)<=160 && event.getY(0)<=150) {
                    B b = new B(getApplicationContext());
                    relativeLayout.addView(b);
                }
                return true;
            }
        })
```

;

Comment: Need more detail, code, something. Multi-touch and "pulling" are not standard in the basic Android activity

Comment: I updated my post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm to understand your question correctly, I think you want to use an `OnClickListener` instead of an `OnTouchListener`.

Try this:

```
a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        B b = new B(getApplicationContext());
        relativeLayout.addView(b);
    }
});
```

This is assuming you want to tap anywhere within `a` to add `b` to your `relativeLayout`. If you want to tap a specific area within `a` you should add a new view to `a` that covers that area and then add the click listener to that new view.